# 2010 Nissan Sentra - Idling rough in reverse, occasionally stalls when stopping

Tags: nissan, rough-idle, air-intake, stall, sentra

Been having an issue with my 2010 Sentra where the idle in reverse is very rough and has very little power.

As well when making abrupt stops in drive the car will occasionally stall, but 
start back up no problem.

There are no errors when checking the codes either.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the engine moving while in reverse we noticed there was a crack in the air intake hose you wouldn't see when not in reverse, patched it up before ordering the part to determine if it was the issue and it solved my issues!

Just sharing in case someone else is having this issue.

Comment: Way to answer your own question! Thanks for providing your answer :o)